# Flask select form not sending full option value in request

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a select field in a form that is populated with values based on column names in an external table.

```
 <select name="joincolumn1" form ="form1" required>
        {% for option in options['tempTable'] %}
         <option value = {{option}}>{{option}}</option>
        {% endfor%}
      </select>
```

The issue is: whenever there is a option that has more than one word The request won't send the full value.

If the selected value is "hostname" it works just fine.
If it is "host name"  the value comes back as "host"

```
print(request.args['joincolumn1'])
```

not the full name of the selected value.

Comment: What do you get from `print(request.form.to_dict().get('joincolumn1'))`?

Comment: That one returns all of the select possiblities for the form. The values are still truncated

Comment: I don't get it, this is the reverse of the behaviour I get and I have dropdowns all over my app. I only got the truncation behaviour If `value="{{option}}"` wasn't enclosed in double quotes, and `request.form.to_dict()` certainly only gives me the option selected from the dropdown. Are you able to make an MCVE that illustrates this issue?

Comment: Issue resolved itself. the double quotes were not included in the html I was testing until I did a hard refresh cntrl+f5

I edited the question so that it makes sense now. Thanks